What is a good source of information on OR academic positions?
As the title says: I was wondering if there exist dedicated websitse, mailing lists, or any other good sources posting information regarding open academic positions in OR (say any level, including PhD positions).
Put differently: where should one post an open position in OR? Where should one look if looking for an academic position in OR?

I wouldn't say it's a particularly good source, but Research Gate also has a Jobs page with PhD and post-doc positions.

If you belong to INFORMS, you can find an "Available Positions" community on their Connect platform where job openings (mainly academic) are posted. I think most but not all are in the U.S.
There is an email list called Opt-Net that frequently contains messages academic openings (primarily but not exclusively in Europe, and probably mostly related to optimization).
I suspect that if you join the UK Operational Research Society, IFORS or some other professional group you will also find job listings.
You likely can find some on LinkedIn as well, although my sense is they tend to skew toward real-world jobs as opposed to academic positions.
You might also want to look at this related question regarding internships. Some of the links there might help.
